# @Mention.js returns no result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried using Mention.js from [this](https://github.com/jakiestfu/Mention.js).

My Search.html contains,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div> 
<textarea id="try"></textarea>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jakiestfu.github.io/Mention.js/javascripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js">

  $('#try').mention({
  delimiter: '@',
  users: [{
      username: "ashley"
  }, { 
      username: "roger"
  }, { 
      username: "frecklefart123"
  }]
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The box returns no result. Any help in pointing my mistake is appreciated. Thanks.

P.S This is pseudocode, the actual usage is in my rails app in search.html.erb which has Typeahead dependancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation of Mention.js

**Dependencies**

**jQuery** , 
**Typeahead**

so you should use

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jakiestfu.github.io/Mention.js/javascripts/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>
```

then the plugin

```
<script type="text/javascript">(function(e){e.fn.extend({mention:function(t){this.opts={users:[],delimiter:"@",sensitive:true,queryBy:["name","username"],typeaheadOpts:{}};var n=e.extend({},this.opts,t),r=function(){if(typeof e=="undefined"){throw new Error("jQuery is Required")}else{if(typeof e.fn.typeahead=="undefined"){throw new Error("Typeahead is Required")}}return true},i=function(e,t){var r;for(r=t;r>=0;r--){if(e[r]==n.delimiter){break}}return e.substring(r,t)},s=function(e){var t;for(t in n.queryBy){if(e[n.queryBy[t]]){var r=e[n.queryBy[t]].toLowerCase(),i=this.query.toLowerCase().match(new RegExp(n.delimiter+"\\w+","g")),s;if(!!i){for(s=0;s<i.length;s++){var o=i[s].substring(1).toLowerCase(),u=new RegExp(n.delimiter+r,"g"),a=this.query.toLowerCase().match(u);if(r.indexOf(o)!=-1&&a===null){return true}}}}}},o=function(e){var t=this.query,r=this.$element[0].selectionStart,i;for(i=r;i>=0;i--){if(t[i]==n.delimiter){break}}var s=t.substring(i,r),o=t.substring(0,i),u=t.substring(r),t=o+n.delimiter+e+u;this.tempQuery=t;return t},u=function(e){if(e.length&&n.sensitive){var t=i(this.query,this.$element[0].selectionStart).substring(1),r,s=e.length,o={highest:[],high:[],med:[],low:[]},u=[];if(t.length==1){for(r=0;r<s;r++){var a=e[r];if(a.username[0]==t){o.highest.push(a)}else if(a.username[0].toLowerCase()==t.toLowerCase()){o.high.push(a)}else if(a.username.indexOf(t)!=-1){o.med.push(a)}else{o.low.push(a)}}for(r in o){var f;for(f in o[r]){u.push(o[r][f])}}return u}}return e},a=function(t){var r=this;t=e(t).map(function(t,i){t=e(r.options.item).attr("data-value",i.username);var s=e("<div />");if(i.image){s.append('<img class="mention_image" src="'+i.image+'">')}if(i.name){s.append('<b class="mention_name">'+i.name+"</b>")}if(i.username){s.append('<span class="mention_username"> '+n.delimiter+i.username+"</span>")}t.find("a").html(r.highlighter(s.html()));return t[0]});t.first().addClass("active");this.$menu.html(t);return this};e.fn.typeahead.Constructor.prototype.render=a;return this.each(function(){var t=e(this);if(r()){t.typeahead(e.extend({source:n.users,matcher:s,updater:o,sorter:u},n.typeaheadOpts))}})}})})(jQuery)</script>
```

or just download the Mention.js file and link it to your code

and then

```
<script>
  // run your code here
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, it was dependency issue :)

Answer (score 0):

`$('#try').mention({...)};`it should be in `$( document ).ready()`.